# initializing string to null termination in order to avoid memset

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c-strings

I wrote this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c[10]="";                //Q

    if(c[2]=='\0')
        printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

In the line `//Q` is it the entire string set to `'\0'` or just the *0th* index? Though on checking the output it prints **hello** but I am not sure if its some value by fallacy or by design?

Comment: If you want to be sure just `bzero` it. That makes your intent a lot more clear.

Comment: Note that "avoid `memset`"  is only visual here. It is fairly likely that some `memset` variant is called under the hood to initialize this array anyway. You can examine the assembly code generated for your platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

and

> 10. ...If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not 
>       initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

Thus all elements of the character array will be zero-initialized.

Comment: Does the rule 21 makes it any faster than `memset`?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus The compiler can itself call memset.:)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set only one char to zero (i your case the first one) you need to assign zero to this char.

```
void foo()
{
    char c[64];
    c[0] = 0;
    /* ... */
}
```